# tornado periodiccallback fails on second run

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to make several `PeriodicCallback`'s to monitor different parts of the server, however when i run the server it seem to run the `PeriodicCallback` the first time but that that, i get following error during next interval

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 830, in _run
    self.callback()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

When the server is running `start_scheduler` in `server.py` is being executed. why am i getting this error on the second run og the `PeriodicCallback`?

**MonitorManager**

```
class MonitorManager:

    instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = cls()
        return cls.instance



    def __init__(self):

        self.node_scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(
            self.test(),
            1000*100)

    def test(self):
        print('done')
```

**server.py**

```
class SchedulerServer:

    VERSION = 'v1'

    singleton = None

    def __init__(self, scheduler_instance, monitor_instance):
        # Start scheduler
        self.scheduler_manager = scheduler_instance
        self.monitor_manager = monitor_instance

        self.tornado_settings = dict(
            debug=settings.DEBUG,
            static_path=settings.STATIC_DIR_PATH,
            template_path=settings.TEMPLATE_DIR_PATH,
            scheduler_manager=self.scheduler_manager,
            monitor_manager=self.monitor_manager
        )

        # Setup server
        URLS = [
            # Index page
            (r'/', index_page.Handler)
        ]
        self.application = tornado.web.Application(URLS, **self.tornado_settings)

    def start_scheduler(self):
        self.monitor_manager.start()
        self.scheduler_manager.start()

    def stop_scheduler(self):
        self.scheduler_manager.stop()

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        if not cls.singleton:

            cls.singleton = cls(
                scheduler_manager.SchedulerManager.get_instance(),
                monitor_manager.MonitorManager.get_instance()
            )
            cls.singleton.start_scheduler()

            cls.singleton.application.listen(settings.HTTP_PORT, settings.HTTP_ADDRESS)
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in `PeriodicCallback` call. `PeriodicCallback` requires a [callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) as the first argument, but here

```
self.node_scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(
            self.test(),
            1000*100)
```

there is a straight call of `self.test()`, which prints `done` and returns `None`, and this `None` is saved for future use of `PeriodicCallback`.
So actually, there was an error on the first execution of `PeriodicCallback`, not on the second.

To fix it pass to `PeriodicCallback` any callable object, for example, `self.test`:

```
self.node_scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(
            self.test,
            1000*100)
```